# Counting all rows of table once, after a series of Union Alls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Creating data quality rules- and in this case, I'm doing a null check on a few columns of a table. What I'm trying to figure out, is how to get the total record\row count for the table to be queried once(to minimize stress on the server), but populate in all rows of the result set in the column TOTAL_COUNT. I believe that I need a left join- just trying to learn how & where to use it.

So the code that I have, so far is:

```
SELECT
 CAST('RULE_ID_1') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS RULE_ID
 CAST('DB_NAME_HERE') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DB_NAME
 CAST('1STCOLUMN') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS COLUMN_NAME
 A.DEFECT_COUNT AS DEFECT_COUNT
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS DEFECT_COUNT
FROM [Name of Db]
WHERE [Name of column 1] IS NULL
AND DateField = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) A
UNION ALL

SELECT
 CAST('RULE_ID_2') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS RULE_ID
 CAST('DB_NAME_HERE') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DB_NAME
 CAST('2NDCOLUMN') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS COLUMN_NAME
 A.DEFECT_COUNT AS DEFECT_COUNT
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS DEFECT_COUNT
FROM [Name of Db]
WHERE [Name of column 2] IS NULL
AND DateField = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) A
UNION ALL

SELECT
 CAST('RULE_ID_3') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS RULE_ID
 CAST('DB_NAME_HERE') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DB_NAME
 CAST('3RDCOLUMN') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS COLUMN_NAME
 A.DEFECT_COUNT AS DEFECT_COUNT
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS DEFECT_COUNT
FROM [Name of Db]
WHERE [Name of column 3] IS NULL
AND DateField = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) A

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 'DB_NAME_HERE' AS DB_NAME, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT FROM [Name of Db] WHERE [What goes here?] IS NULL) B
ON
A.DB_NAME=B.DB_NAME
```

The output| that i need to report out:

| RULE_ID | DB_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DEFECT_COUNT(Nulls) | TOTAL_COUNT(#Rows) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RULE_ID_1 | DB_NAME_HERE | 1STCOLUMN | 5 | 100 |
| RULE_ID_2 | DB_NAME_HERE | 2NDCOLUMN | 0 | 100 |
| RULE_ID_3 | DB_NAME_HERE | 3RDCOLUMN | 2 | 100 |

Comment: Total row count for that one day *(all your other queries filter for 'yesterday')*, or for all days?  Then, why does ***anything*** need to go in the `WHERE ??? IS NULL`?  Do you want all rows, or just rows where at least one of columns 1, 2, 3 contains a `NULL`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results, and with the emphasis on "minimal" - we don't need your production code, rather code that represents the problem in its simplest form.

Comment: This needs a clear example of the data and output required. And re `total record/row count` - it's `row count`.

Comment: @MatBailie Row count for the previous day for both the total row count, as well as the individual records in the columns- the where clause is checking that particular column for null records. All rows need to be checked for null values, and the defect count is the number of nulls, in this case. Will post a data output. Sorry, should've done that.

Comment: Your sample output does not match your description. In your description all three rows should have the same value in TotalRows. Please read the Minimal Reproducible Example link in the comments above.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I'd be breaking the query up into different portions for counting nulls, spaces, unique values, etc. The count would be the same, as updated in the sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've laid your query out is creating a lot of extra effort for both you and the SQL Server.

First, You can do most of in in a single query, if you adopt a very slightly different structure using "conditional aggregation"; that is `COUNT()` with a `CASE` expression inside it.

Then you can simply add another column for the `TOTAL_COUNT`.  Though, I'm not entirely sure what you want for that total, so I've included a few options...

```
SELECT
  CAST('DB_NAME_HERE') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DB_NAME,

  CAST('1STCOLUMN')    AS VARCHAR(255))                   AS RULE_ID_1_COLUMN_NAME,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name of column 1] IS NULL THEN 1 END)  AS RULE_ID_1_DEFECT_COUNT,

  CAST('2NDCOLUMN')    AS VARCHAR(255))                   AS RULE_ID_2_COLUMN_NAME,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name of column 2] IS NULL THEN 1 END)  AS RULE_ID_2_DEFECT_COUNT,

  CAST('3RDCOLUMN')    AS VARCHAR(255))                   AS RULE_ID_3_COLUMN_NAME,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name of column 3] IS NULL THEN 1 END)  AS RULE_ID_3_DEFECT_COUNT,

  COUNT(*)                                                AS TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name of column 1] IS NULL
               OR [Name of column 2] IS NULL 
               OR [Name of column 3] IS NULL THEN 1 END)  AS TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS_WITH_NULLS,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Name of Db])                     AS TABLE_TOTAL_ROWS
FROM
  [Name of Db]
WHERE
  DateField = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Then, if you really must have your existing format, you can un-pivot it...

```
WITH
  yesterday_summary AS
(
  SELECT
    CAST('DB_NAME_HERE') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DB_NAME,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name of column 1] IS NULL THEN 1 END)  AS RULE_ID_1_DEFECT_COUNT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name of column 2] IS NULL THEN 1 END)  AS RULE_ID_2_DEFECT_COUNT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [Name of column 3] IS NULL THEN 1 END)  AS RULE_ID_3_DEFECT_COUNT
  FROM
    [Name of Db]
  WHERE
    DateField = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
)
SELECT
  y.DB_NAME,
  p.RULE_ID,
  p.COLUMN_NAME,
  p.DEFECT_COUNT,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Name of Db])   AS TABLE_TOTAL_ROWS
FROM
  yesterday_summary   AS y
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    ('RULE_ID_1', '1STCOLUMN', y.RULE_ID_1_DEFECT_COUNT),
    ('RULE_ID_2', '2NDCOLUMN', y.RULE_ID_2_DEFECT_COUNT),
    ('RULE_ID_3', '3RDCOLUMN', y.RULE_ID_3_DEFECT_COUNT)
)
  AS p(RULE_ID, COLUMN_NAME, DEFECT_COUNT)
```

Comment: I think that I got it mostly working, @MatBallie. There's just an error that I'm getting regarding the 'with' statement, possibly;

Comment: @supernova Make sure any sql statement prior to the `WITH` is terminated by a `;`

Comment: thanks, that worked. So the pivoted portion is working- however, i noticed that the un-pivoted section is returning 0 defect_counts for RULE_ID_1, when there actually is a null count(defect count) of 412,905 in the pivoted portion of the output. I have the coding laid out exactly as above- and suspect it's the "y." or "p." somewhere- been playing with it with no success, yet. Also, TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS and TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS_WITH_NULLS appear to be the same\duplicate value. I commented out "COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS," and it works well- only showing TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS_WITH_NULLS & TABLE_TOTAL_ROWS

Comment: @Supernova - Debugging of this nature is impossible in comments.  Create a test data set, representative of the failures you're seeing and add that test data to the question, along with the results you need from that test set.  Then you can say "for ***this*** exact test set, I should see ***these*** exact results.  There's more information on why and how here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Supernova If `TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS` and `TOTAL_DAILY_ROWS_WITH_NULLS` are the same value, all that means is that every row has at least one `NULL`.  Had there been any rows without a `NULL`, the resulting values would have been different.